# Select en codeigniter produce Nombre ?> en lugar de una lista de nombres

Tags: php, codeigniter, select

Uso codeigniter y php, hago un select y en la vista en lugar de salir un conjuntos de registros del campo Nombre, sale: Nombre ?>

formulario_buscar_cliente.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <TITLE></TITLE>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">         
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php /*echo base_url();*/ ?>/css/estilos.css"> 
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/application/views/css/estilos.css"> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 

        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                margin:0;   
                color:#6a6f8c;  
                font:600 16px/18px 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
            }

            html {
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>    
</head>

<body>
    <br>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li role="presentation" ><a href="http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/index.php/cliente/mostrarInicio">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/index.php/cliente/mostrarDatos/cliente">Ingresar Cliente </a></li>
                        <li role="presentation" ><a href="http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/index.php/cliente/buscarCliente">Buscar Cliente </a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="cuentaxcliente.php">Cuenta Cliente</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="transaccuenta.php">Transación Cuenta</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/index.php/transaccion/IngresarTransaccion">Ingresar Tipo de Transacción</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/index.php/transaccion/BuscarTransaccion">Buscar Tipo de Transacción</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/index.php/cliente/login">Login</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <br><br>    



    <?php
        foreach ($clientes->result() as $c) { ?>
            <ul>
                <li><?php= $c->Nombre ?></li>
            </ul>

        <?php } ?>  
    <br>    


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>            

</body>
</html>
```

main_model

```
<?php  
 class Main_model extends CI_Model  
 {  
    public function __construct() {
        //llamamos al constructor de la clase padre
        parent::__construct();

        //cargamos la base de datos
        $this->load->database();
    }       

    public function insertar($datos){
      $this->db->insert('tbl_cliente', array('DocIdent'=>$datos['documentoDeIdentidad'], 
        'Nombre'=>$datos['nombre'],
        'Apellido'=>$datos['apellido'],
        'Direccion'=>$datos['direccion'],
        'Telefono'=>$datos['telefono'],
        'Estado'=>$datos['estado'],
        'FechaIngreso'=>$datos['fechaIngreso'],
        'Password'=>$datos['password']
      ));
     }

     public function obtenerClientes(){
        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_cliente');

         if($query->num_rows()>0){            
            return $query;            
        }else{
            return false;
        } 
     }
```

cliente_buscar (el controlador)

```
<?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class cliente_buscar extends CI_Controller{
        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->load->database();
            //llamo o incluyo el modelo
            $this->load->model('main_model');

        }

        function listado(){
            $data['clientes'] = $this->main_model->obtenerClientes();
            $this->load->view('formulario_buscar_cliente', $data);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Has considerado cambiar la sintaxis de?

```
<?php= $c->Nombre ?>
```

a

```
<?php echo $c->Nombre; ?>
```

Comment: Sale   syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file

Comment: Pusiste el punto y como `;`?

Comment: ¿Dónde? <?php= $c->Nombre ?> ahí?   Si es en el otro ejemplo, sí @Xerif

Comment: @JhonHernández ¿Puedes colocar como queda el foreach luego de que haces el cambio que sugiero? Parece ser que una llave no cierra correctamente pero la forma de verlo es por el código. Los foreach en las vistas también tienen otra sintaxis, prueba si te funciona:
<?php foreach(tus valores): ?>
content
<?php endforeach; ?>
Es importante que entre la palabra php y lo que viene exista un espacio.

Comment: Usé mejor este y con él funcionó:   <table border="1">
 <?php
 foreach($ver as $fila){
 ?>
     <tr>
         <td>
             <?=$fila->DocIdent;?>
         </td>
         <td>
             <?=$fila->Nombre;?>
         </td>
         <td>
             <?=$fila->Apellido;?>
         </td>
         <td>
             <?=$fila->Direccion;?>
         </td>
         <td>
             <?=$fila->Telefono;?>
         </td>
         
     </tr>
 <?php
     
 }
 ?>
 </table>

Comment: @FranciscoMarcano el operador `<?php=` no existe en php, este `<?=` si existe.

Answer (score 0):

Nombre ?>  es probable que los short open tags los tengas deshabilitados

Entra en el php.ini busca la linea

short_open_tag y colocalo en ON, y reinicia el servidor.

habilitado el short_open_tag escribelo de la siguiente manera:

```
introducir el código aquí
```

si no te soluciona, escribe completo el echo asi:

```
<?php echo $c->Nombre; ?> //sin olvidar el punto y coma.
```

esto es valido con el  short_open_tag habilitado o no.

Espero haberte ayudado.